# Are the decorator streams also implemented as adapters of stream instances or as some other design pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

From C# in Nutshell:
[image]

1. The stream adapters are implemented as adapters of stream instances.

   Are the decorator streams also implemented as adapters of stream
   instances? What design pattern are they implemented?
2. Note that decorator streams are implemented as derived classes of
   `System.Stream` or of its derived classes, while  stream adapters
   are not (but via composition which I guess). So I wonder if adapter
   patterns can be  implemented via either composition or inheritance?

   - Are adapters always implemented in terms of composition instead of inheritance (so that they can handle inputs of different types from
     the ones that they adapt)?
   - Are decorators always implemented in terms of inheritance instead of composition (so that they can always be used in the same way as
     the one that they decorate)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapters generally change the interface, decorators generally do not.

This is why the consumers of the "decorator streams" in your diagrams are able to substitute any of those classes for each other.  The code doesn't change whether it is a Buffered Stream or a Crypto Stream.

Consumers of the Readers and Writer (your Stream Adapters) on the other hand expect a very specific interface that is highly customize and varies wildly from adapter to adapter.  One returns XML nodes, another perhaps primitive types.  They cannot be swapped for each other.

(And there is a "Decorator" pattern straight out of the GoF book, "Design Patterns").

Comment: Thanks. Are adapters always implemented in terms of composition instead of inheritance (so that they can handle inputs of different types from the ones that they adapt)? Are decorators always implemented in terms of inheritance instead of composition (so that they can always be used in the same way as the one that they decorate)?

Comment: No such thing as always.  To your specific questions, while your "Decorator Streams" will need to inherit or implement from a common ancestor, They most certainly use composition as they wrap the "Backing Store Streams".  That is why you don't see a GzipMemroyStream class and a GzipFileStream class or any of the other permutations.  It would cause a concrete class explosion.